# cant get this mysql event to working

Tags: mysql, scheduler

I want this event to get to work.

says that it is waiting for queue and no update are done as intended.

EVENt:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
DELIMITER $$
USE `kickfarted` $$

CREATE EVENT ENDCHECK
ON SCHEDULE AT current_timestamp() + INTERVAL 10 SECOND
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
BEGIN

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE successful_projectid (select project_id from project where status="looking" and pledge_end_date<NOW() and amt_collected>=min_amt);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE failed_projectid (select project_id from project where status="looking" and pledge_end_date<NOW() and amt_collected<min_amt);

update project SET project_status="failed" where project_id in  (select * from failed_projectid);
update project SET project_status="pledged" where project_id in (select * from successful_projectid);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sponsor_charge(select spon_id,project_id from sponsor where project_id in (select * from successful_projectid));

Insert into pledge_success(ps_user_id,ps_project_id,`0`) select spon_id,project_id from sponsor_charge where sponsor_charge.project_id=New.project_id;
update pledge_success SET success_date=NOW where pledge_success.ps_project_id=New.project_id;

Drop temporary tables successful_projectid,failed_projectid,sponsor_charge;

END;
$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: 1) are the events enabled in your mysql? 2) why do you use temporary tables at all?

Comment: They're enabled. WHat other alternative do you suggest?